# How do I split on every other line?

Tags: perl

I am working on a Perl script that processes the output from [ec2-describe-instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-DescribeInstances.html) which is returning its output as follows:

```
INSTANCE\n
TAG\n
INSTANCE\n
TAG\n
INSTANCE\n
TAG\n
```

Is there a way that I can use the [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) function so that the results are split into two line chunks such as the following?

```
INSTANCE\n
TAG\n
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `paste` command ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first arg of `split` should be what separates what you wanted returned.

```
split /(?!^)(?=(?:.*\n.*\n)+\z)/, do { local $/; <> };
```

But that's very inefficient.

---

If you want to output to a handle, you could use:

```
perl -pe'()=split//,""; print "\n" if $. % 2 == 1 && $. > 1'
```

Which is similar to:

```
()=split//,"";
while (<>) {
    print "\n" if $. % 2 == 1 && $. > 1;
    print;
}
```

(I strongly recommend leaving out the `()=split//,"";`.)

`$.` the line number of the last line read.

---

If you want to output to an array, you could use:

```
()=split//,""; 
my @array;
my $buf;
while (<>) {
   $buf .= $_;
   if ($. % 2 == 1) {
      push @array, $buf;
      $buf = '';
   }
}
```

(I strongly recommend leaving out the `()=split//,"";`.)

---

If you're ok with loading everything into memory, you could use

```
()=split//,"";
my @array = do { local $/; <> } =~ /\G.*\n.*\n/g;
```

(I strongly recommend leaving out the `()=split//,"";`.)

Comment: @rob, Updated to produce instead of print.

Comment: It was updated in a a comment 18 hours ago. How is it not answered? Feel free to update the question to further clarify again.

Comment: @rob, In both of my answers, the results are returned split into two line chunks such as "the following". Again, if the result is incorrect, please upate your question to clarify.

Comment: Are you giving me attitude because you don't know how to add a string to an array? It's `push @array, $buf;`

Comment: Beacuse I've provided two solutions that perform the required function, but you keep saying your question isn't answered. Therefore, there's something missing from your question, therefore, it's in need of an update.

Comment: Fine, I've added `split` to my solutions.